# to_xml for fully-qualified trees using acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-tree

I have an ActiveRecord class that uses acts_as_tree.  I'm trying to update the to_xml method so that if a child record's to_xml is called it will return it's xml nested in the parent/ancestor xml to give the fully-qualified path to that resource.  As an example I have Compiler which is a parent of Compiler/Version.  Compiler should be rendered as xml:

While Compiler/Version should render as

I've tried to do this by passing around a fully_qualified flag, but it dies with 'Builder::XmlMarkup#to_ary should return Array'

def to_xml(options={}, &block)
    options[:fully_qualified] ||= true
    options[:indent] ||= 2
    options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])

```
if options[:fully_qualified] and not parent.nil?
```

55:      parent.to_xml(options) do |foo|
        relative_options = options.dup
        relative_options[:fully_qualfied] = false
        relative_options[:skip_instruct] = true
        relative_options.delete(:builder)

```
    foo << to_xml(relative_options)
  end
else
  xml = options[:builder]
  xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
```

66:      xml.parameter(:name => name, &block)
    end
  end

The method works fine for the case of Compiler, but fails for Compiler/Version:

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/builder/xmlbase.rb:133:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/builder/xmlbase.rb:133:in`call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/builder/xmlbase.rb:133:in `_nested_structures'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/builder/xmlbase.rb:57:in`method_missing'
app/models/parameter.rb:66:in `to_xml'
app/models/parameter.rb:55:in`to_xml'

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can't call to_xml on any singular-association. to_xml on parent and parameter (both has_one relationships) failed, but if I did the lookup with find_by_id it worked:

def to_xml(options={}, &block)
    my_options = options.dup
    my_options[:fully_qualified] = true unless my_options.has_key?(:fully_qualified)
    my_options[:only] = [:name]

```
if my_options[:fully_qualified] and not parent.nil?
   # do block here fails with 'Builder::XmlMarkup#to_ary should return Array'
   # if called as parent.to_xml, so call on explicit lookup of parent and
   # it works
   p = self.class.find_by_id(parent_id)
   p.to_xml(my_options) do |xml|
     relative_options = my_options.dup
     relative_options[:builder] = xml
     relative_options[:fully_qualified] = false
     relative_options[:skip_instruct] = true

     to_xml(relative_options, &block)
   end
else
  super(my_options, &block)
end
```

end